# casting to base class, and calling its virtual method results in stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual void UpdateLastLogin()
    {
        // business of last login here
    }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public override void UpdateLastLogin()
    {
        // logging something specific to person
        ((Person)this).UpdatelastLogin();
    }
}
```

Why Above code throws STACKOVERFLOW exception?

But this doesn't:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual void UpdateLastLogin()
    {
        // business of last login here
    }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public override void UpdateLastLogin()
    {
        // logging something specific to person
        base.UpdatelastLogin();
    }
}
```

Comment: Both should have a syntax error because UpdatelastLogin != UpdateLastLogin

Comment: `((Person)this).UpdatelastLogin();` calls it self not a base class method. So here is a recursion and stack overflow as a result.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because *base* keyword disables *virtual method invocation*, but casting doesn't.

Let's break it down:

With `virtual`s and `override`s, C# has an algorithm to find the correct method to call. This algorithm is called *virtual method invocation*.

When C# compiler is to invoke a method that has `override` modifier, it tries to find the **most overriden method**. That is, it goes down the inheritance hierarchy of the *run-time type* to find the most overriden method. In this case, when you cast the `Student` to its base class `Person`, in **run-time**, what you really have is a derived class from `Person`. Thus C# compiler tries to find the *most overriden method*, that is, a method that exists in the `Student` class, and it calls that method. But that method again tries to cast `Student` to `Person` and again the chain goes on and on. Thus you see `StackOverflowException`.

However, when you use `base` to call the *overridden base method*, then compiler treats with that method (`Person.UpdateLastLogin`) as a **non-virtual method** and won't apply *virtual method invocation* and *resolution* to it.

C# specification has a pretty reasonable explanation on `override` and `virtual`. I encourage you to read its **17.5.3 Virtual methods** and **17.5.4 Override methods** sections. Specifically quoted from specification:

> A base-access disables the virtual invocation mechanism and simply treats the base method as a non-virtual method.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean to call the base class implementation, use the [`base` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hfw7t1ce.aspx):

```
base.UpdatelastLogin();
```

Casting the reference to the base class really *does nothing*. That's the beauty of object-oriented programming! You don't need to know what type something is - you simply call a method on an object, and it's up the the implementation of that object how to behave.

Once you instantiate the child class, the entry in that object's [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) for `UpdateLastLogin()` is always going to point to the child class, no matter the type of the reference.

Comment: Well, technically if he used the new keyword in the Student class on the UpdateLastLogin method, he would be able to execute the base method by using ((Person)this).UpdateLastLogin()

Comment: @ToddBowles Agreed, but I figure that might be a bit confusing, given the OP's current understanding.